# Sed: specific exact two match

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have this line in a file. The blanks between the words can be tabs or spaces

```
#define FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR   Function(2)     /* FN_ comment*/
```

and I wanted output to be like this :

```
2:"FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR",
```

I have this code:

```
echo -e "#define \t \t\t FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR \t\t\t  Function(2)\t     /* FN_ comment*/" |sed "s/.*\(\([[:blank:]]\)FN_*[_a-zA-Z]*\).[^ ].*(\([^\)]*\)).*/\3:\"\1\",/"
```

But the output is with preceding blanks between quote and FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR :

```
2:"     FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR",
```

How can I avoid it? Solution has to be robust spaces or tabs must not affect the selection. My solution has to be in sed, Preferably in one single command.

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to Aaron. The solution I preferred is this

```
echo -e "#define \t\t\r FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR \t\r\t\t  Function(2)\t     /* FN_ comment*/" |sed "s/.*\s\(FN_*[_a-zA-Z]*\).[^ ].*(\([^\)]*\)).*/\2:\"\1\",/"
```

Comment: If `awk` is an option: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ \t()]+"} {print $4 ":\"" $2 "\","}' file`

Comment: a little remark: `FN_*[_a-zA-Z]*` is equivalent to `FN[_a-zA-Z]*`, that might not be what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sed command, the first capturing group which starts with your fist opening `\(` contains the `[[:blank:]]` class which matches the spaces that precede `FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR`.

I suggest using the following command :

```
sed -E 's/.*\s(FN_*[_a-zA-Z]*).*\(([^)])\).*/\2:\"\1"/'
```

Tested [here](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUHXVUG9WF9PK6ZYw80vXis6PlG3ylE3KlZLEyimoREdpxmrGQNk68cYWcUoxRgq6av//6@ckpqWmZeqEFMCREACqNMxNMQ/Hki7@QW7Oof4B4ElgFIKbqV5ySWZ@XkaRpogLhDoa4E0KCTn5@am5pVo6QMA).

In this command I use `-E` to switch to extended regular expressions where `(...)` denotes capturing groups while `\(...\)` denotes literal brackets. It also enables me (on modern GNU sed at least) to use `\s` to represent blanks.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron Your answer gave me the perfect clue. .*\s would do the trick. This will work without -E
echo -e "#define \t\t\r FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR \t\r\t\t  Function(2)\t     /* FN_ comment*/" |sed "s/.*\s\(FN_*[_a-zA-Z]*\).[^ ].*(\([^\)]*\)).*/\2:\"\1\",/"

Comment: @RamananT note that `\s` acts the same as `[:blank:]` does (it's a more modern notation but also less portable in regards to older `sed` versions). The difference is that this time you didn't include it in your first capturing group

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]*\)[^(]*(\(.\).*/\2:"\1",/' input_file
2:"FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR",
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]](FN[^[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+\(([^()])\).*/\2:"\1",/'
```

If you have  a GNU sed, you can replace `[[:blank:]]` with `\s` (any whitespace) and `[^[:blank:]]` with `\S` (any non-whitespace):

```sh
sed -E 's/.*\s(FN\S*)\s+\S+\(([^()]*)\).*/\2:"\1",/'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/vd5erC):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='#define FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR   Function(2)     /* FN_ comment*/'
sed -E 's/.*[[:blank:]](FN[^[:blank:]]*)[[:blank:]]+[^[:blank:]]+\(([^()]*)\).*/\2:"\1",/' <<< "$s"
## => 2:"FN_AUTO_FN_FNSECTOR",
```

Note that `-E` option allows POSIX ERE syntax where unescaped `+` is a *one or more* quantifier, and to define capturing groups you need unescaped pairs of parentheses.

*Pattern details*:

- `.*` - any text
- `[[:blank:]]` - a horizontal whitespace char
- `(FN[^[:blank:]]*)` - Group 1: `FN` and zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `[[:blank:]]+` - one or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `[^[:blank:]]+`
- `\(` -  a literal `(` char (in POSIX BRE, it should not be escaped, but in ERE, it must)
- `([^()]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` (note that `(` and `)` inside bracket expressions do not need escaping in any POSIX (and all non-POSIX that I know of) regex flavor)
- `\)` - a literal `)` in POSIX ERE
- `.*` - any text